# Fit method of my model does not perform training after being loaded with load_model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have trained a `NN` using `tf.keras` and saved the whole model with `ModelCheckpoint` in a `.h5` file.

However, when I restore it with `models.load_model` and then train it again with the method `fit`, it only returns a `History` object and does nothing more.

Below is the `minimal example` for the training:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# Creates dummy data
train_x = np.random.randint(10,size=40).reshape(-1,1)
train_y = np.random.randint(2,size=40).reshape(-1,1)
train_set = (train_x,train_y)
val_x = np.random.randint(10,size=20).reshape(-1,1)
val_y = np.random.randint(2,size=20).reshape(-1,1)
val_set = (val_x,val_y)

# Set Learning Rate Decay
import math
def step_decay(epoch):
    print('--- Epoch:',epoch)
    print(tf.keras.callbacks.History())
    init_lr = 0.001
    drop = 0.9
    epochs_drop = 1.0
    lr = init_lr*math.pow(drop,math.floor((1+epoch)/epochs_drop))
    return(lr)

lr_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler(step_decay)

# Saves the whole model
cp_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint('model.h5',
    save_weights_only=False,
    verbose=True)

# Creates the model
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,activation='relu',use_bias=False,input_dim=(1)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(100,activation='relu',use_bias=False))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,activation='relu',use_bias=False))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
        optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
        metrics=['accuracy'])


print('Learning Rate: ',tf.keras.backend.eval(model.optimizer.lr))
# Train the model
model.fit(x=train_set[0],y=train_set[1],epochs=2,steps_per_epoch=40,
            validation_data=val_set,validation_steps=20,
            callbacks=[lr_callback,cp_callback])
print('Learning Rate: ',tf.keras.backend.eval(model.optimizer.lr))
```

The code I am currently using to load it again is the follow one.

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# Creates dummy data
train_x = np.random.randint(10,size=40).reshape(-1,1)
train_y = np.random.randint(2,size=40).reshape(-1,1)
train_set = (train_x,train_y)
val_x = np.random.randint(10,size=20).reshape(-1,1)
val_y = np.random.randint(2,size=20).reshape(-1,1)
val_set = (val_x,val_y)

# Set Learning Rate Decay
import math
def step_decay(epoch):
    print('--- Epoch:',epoch)
    print(tf.keras.callbacks.History())
    init_lr = 0.001
    drop = 0.9
    epochs_drop = 1.0
    lr = init_lr*math.pow(drop,math.floor((1+epoch)/epochs_drop))
    return(lr)

lr_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler(step_decay)

# Saves the whole model
cp_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint('model.h5',
    save_weights_only=False,
    verbose=True)

# Load model
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model.h5')

print('Learning Rate: ',tf.keras.backend.eval(model.optimizer.lr))
model.fit(x=train_set[0],y=train_set[1],epochs=2,steps_per_epoch=40,
            validation_data=val_set,validation_steps=20,initial_epoch=3,
            callbacks=[lr_callback,cp_callback])
```

As you can observe when running it is that the learning rate is restored hence the whole model as well, or at least that's what I think. However, after running `model.fit(...)` it does nothing but return `<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History object at 0x7f11c81cb940>`. Any idea how to allow it to train again?

**EDIT**: I also tried to compile it by setting the `compile` attribute of `load_model` to true.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to compile it after loading?

Comment: Yes, I did. But I got the same result.